# Is it possible to make outbound call using SIP to PSTN with Twilio?

Tags: twilio, sip, voip

What I'm trying to achieve is the following: Use Twilio's Voice API to make an outbound call to a PSTN mobile number, however, instead of using Twilio's routing (which is 10x more expensive than normal SIP providers in my region), I want to use a 3rd-party SIP Trunk to perform the call.

The two areas I can't figure out are:

1. Can Twilio even do this when using a standard SIP Trunk
2. And/or, does the SIP Trunk need certain features for this to work (so I can't just signup for any old SIP Trunk)

I see Twilio can dial a SIP URI, however, I can't see how the SIP Trunk will route that call to the PSTN (ie. it seems it can only dial the SIP user as the final destination). Twilio has recently introduced BYOC - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/bring-your-own-carrier-byoc - which looked hopeful, however, when setting up the Origination Target you can only provide the SIP URI. This is the technical point I don't really understand, since my SIP Trunk requires a username and password to authenticate before making a call, and the BYOC setup doesn't offer this. Is there some special feature the SIP Trunk needs to work?

I think I'm missing something fundamental here, because I can't see a way of making this work (maybe it's not possible without a very specialized setup). So any help getting on the right track is appreciated (I did try Twilio Support, but they seem as clueless as I am).

Answer (score 2):

So I can answer my own question for anyone coming across this post. You can use a standard SIP Trunk with Twilio's BYOC. Twilio sends an INVITE request to the SIP address entered in as the Origination on the BYOC setup. However, it must use IP address authentication - there's no way to use standard SIP credential authentication.

The ip addresses used depends on the DC it's coming from. See signalling IPs here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-interface#ip-address-whitelist

You can also append the "edge" parameter in the Origination SIP URI to dictate which Twilio DC it comes from - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/receiving-sip#SIP-URI-edge

For additional security, you could consider Twilio's private Interconnect option, or you could append some custom arguments to the SIP URI, which could be authenticated on the SIP Trunk side when it receives the INVITE - however, this would require a custom setup to achieve that, and whatever argument you use for authentication would be visible in the URI.